# What is the most effecient way to write this SQL query?

Tags: sql, mysql

I have two lists of ids. List A and List B. Both of these lists are actually the results of SQL queries (QUERY A and QUERY B respectively).

I want to 'filter' List A, by removing the ids in List A if they appear in list B.

So for example if list A looks like this:

1, 2, 3, 4, 7

and List B looks like this:

2,7

then the 'filtered' List A should have ids 2 and 7 removed, and so should look like this:

1, 3, 4

I want to write an SQL query like this (pseudo code of course):

SELECT id FROM (QUERYA) as temp_table where id not in (QUERYB)

Answer (score 3):

Using classic SQL:

```
select [distinct] number
from list_a
where number not in (
    select distinct number from list_b
);
```

I've put the first `"distinct"` in square brackets since I'm unsure as to whether you wanted duplicates removed (remove either the brackets or the entire word). The second `"distinct"` should be left in just in case your DBMS doesn't optimize `IN` clauses.

It *may* be faster (measure, don't guess) with an left join along the lines of:

```
select [distinct] list_a.number from list_a
left join list_b on list_a.number = list_b.number
where list_b.number is null;
```

Same deal with the `"[distinct]"`.

Comment: I think in your second query you meant to use a left OUTER join

Comment: Sorry, ignore my previous comment -- it's irrelevant.

Answer (score 2):

see [Doing INTERSECT and MINUS in MySQL](http://www.bitbybit.dk/carsten/blog/?p=71)

Answer (score 1):

The query:

```
select id 
from ListA
where id not in (
    select id 
    from ListB)
```

will give you the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure which way is the best. As my previous impression, the perforamnce could be very different depends on situtation and the size of the tables.

1.

```
select id 
from ListA
where id not in (
    select id 
    from ListB)
```

2.

```
select ListA.id 
from ListA
left join ListB on ListA.id=ListB.id
where ListB.id is null
```

3.

```
select id 
from ListA
where not exists (
    select * 
    from ListB where ListB.id=ListA.id)
```

The 2) should be the fastest usually, as it does inner join not sub-queries.

Some people may suggest 3) rather then 1) beause it use "exists" which does not read data from table.